How to determine whether to use query parameters or body in GET requests when integrating with different APIs?
I am working with two different APIs, both using GET requests but handling request data differently:

API 1 requires the data to be sent in the request body, even though the HTTP method is GET.
Example:
$config = [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'url' => 'http://example.com/api/endpoint',
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'body' => [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ],
];


API 2 requires the data to be sent as query parameters in the URL.
Example:
$config = [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'url' => 'http://example.com/api/endpoint',
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'query' => [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ],
];



Both APIs work with the GET method, but their requirements for passing data are different. This makes it challenging to decide when to use query parameters and when to use the request body for a GET request.
Questions:

How can I determine whether to use query parameters (query) or the request body (body) for a GET request?
Is it common or correct for a GET request to accept data in the body, even though the HTTP specification discourages it?
How can I design a generic HTTP client (e.g., using Guzzle) to handle these differences dynamically based on the API's requirements?

Any guidance, best practices, or examples would be appreciated!
 $options = ['headers' => $request['headers']];

        if ($request['method'] === 'GET') {
            if ($request['isRequestRawBody']) {
                $options['body'] = json_encode($request['body']);
            } else {
                $options['query'] = $request['body'];
            }
        } else {
            $contentType = $request['headers']['Content-Type'] ?? '';

            switch ($contentType) {
                case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                    $options['form_params'] = $request['body'];
                    break;
                case 'application/json':
                    $options['json'] = $request['body'];
                    break;
                case 'multipart/form-data':
                    $options['multipart'] = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
                        return ['name' => $key, 'contents' => $value];
                    }, array_keys($request['body']), $request['body']);
                    break;
                default:
                    $options['body'] = $request['body'];
            }
        }

        return $options;


How can I determine whether to use query parameters (query) or the request body (body) for a GET request?...Read the documentation for the relevant API

@ADyson yes that's the only option I have but I was curious If I can handle all get request in one unified way so that my baseHttpClient work smoothly as current situation will give me more conditions

How can I design a generic HTTP client (e.g., using Guzzle) to handle these differences dynamically... you'd have to have a lookup data store which holds the specification of each API you want to support. There's no generic solution to this, every API is unique. Some may follow a similar design pattern but there are always little differences

A GET request should never have a request body. The HTTP protocol specification does not allow it. It is possible that the contents of your body properties are somehow translated to query parameters (or ignored completely).
It is technically possible to submit a body with a GET request, but this is not widely supported or required by HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 standards.
If you need a body, use POST, PUT or PATCH methods. Every single API I’ve seen that takes JSON input uses a different method. You could URL encode JSON, but you’d be limited to URL length.
GET is meant to retrieve data, which usually doesn’t require submitting a lot of information in your request.
If you are implementing a client, you can safely ignore bodies in GET requests.
RFC9112 states:
A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a GET request unless it is made directly to an origin server that has previously indicated, in or out of band, that such a request has a purpose and will be adequately supported. An origin server SHOULD NOT rely on private agreements to receive content, since participants in HTTP communication are often unaware of intermediaries along the request chain.
Edit: An HTTP OPTIONS request can often provide more information on how the origin would handle specific requests. Otherwise, you may have to deal with it on a case-by-case basis. Sending JSON to a GET endpoint is a rare requirement.

"unless it is made directly to an origin server that has previously indicated, in or out of band, that such a request has a purpose and will be adequately supported." does not sound like "never" to me. And if the API documents that it supports a request body in the GET request, then the "has previously indicated" condition is fulfilled.

@knittl that's my concern too as this request is in get but the body is passed in json and that is something which I have to conditionally check if particular api then send body else query

I agree. It’s not the standard use case, but under these specific conditions, there should be some kind of indicator that these conditions are met. Try sending an OPTIONS request and look for Accept headers.
